Can't find a way to use the grease pencil to directly draw filled shapes
I'm currently working on my workflow for a lightbox project (you can google Hari&Deepti to have an idea of what I'm looking to create), and I would like to create and render my projects in 3D before printing and cutting the paper layers to have better control over the design and the rendering.
I managed to create a nice render by drawing the layers in a separate software, then converting the lines to vector and importing them in Blender.
This is what I got :  
Now, I would like to directly draw the layers in Blender with the grease pencil (or maybe there's a better option but I doubt it could be faster) to save time and have better artistic freedom.
I've been trying for few days but I just can't get it to work like I want. I can draw what I want, but then when I need to fill the areas it doesn't work :

I've tried a lot of things, playing with the filler tool options, making sure the material as the "fill" option enable, that my shape is correctly closed (still not sure how to shake that), etc... but nothing works.
Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated ! Thanks !
